# serializer.data and serializer.validated_data is blank when a serializer is initialized by dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**SOLVED** (reason on the bottom)

I am building an app using django and drf.
While testing a serializer, I found the serializer could not save data to database because of null constraints.
Below is the test code, serializer and model.

```
location_serializer_data: LocationDict = {
    'address': 'address',
    'latitude': 11.1,
    'longitude': 22.2,
}


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_deserializing(self):
    serializer = LocationSerializer(data=location_serializer_data)
    serializer.is_valid()
    new_location = serializer.save() # < where the test explodes
```

Here is the error message

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: locations_location.latitude`

I found that `serializer.initial_data` gets the data appropriately, but after `serializer.is_valid()`, two of `serializer.data`, `serializer.validated_data` become blank dict.

I searched a bit but I found no clue of what was causing this.

- this is my serializer class

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from locations.models import Location
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('address', 'latitude', 'longitude')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'address': {'required': True},
            'latitude': {
                'required': True,
                'validators': [MaxValueValidator(90), MinValueValidator(-90)]
            },
            'longitude': {
                'required': True,
                'validators': [MaxValueValidator(180), MinValueValidator(-180)]
            },
        }
```

also, validation is not performed at all

++
I solved the problem by editing the Location model.

```
from django.db import models


class Location(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name='address',max_length=255)
    latitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name='latitude',editable=False)
    longitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name='longitude',editable=False)
```

After deleting `editable=False`, serializer worked fine.
Is it a bug or intended?

Comment: have you written any `validate` function in your ```LocationSerializer```. paste your LocationSerializer as well

Answer (score 3):

.is_valid() method validates but does not raise the error by itself. We can do serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True). It raises validation error if the data is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code should help you

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_deserializing(self):
    serializer = LocationSerializer(data=location_serializer_data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # < Now code will raise error here
    new_location = serializer.save()
```

This will ensure that exception is raised at the validation level

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that the the field `latitude` does not exists in the `LocationSerializer` because it got "cleaned out" by the serializer validation. If it's possible, please share the detail on `LocationSerializer` so we can help further.